# 5800MICRA Transmitter in Door with Transom

Tags: security

I'm installing a home security system based around Honeywell products.  I'd like to use 5800MICRA recessed transmitters for all windows/doors to maintain a clean install.  Attached is a picture of my front door during the construction of the home (the home is now finished; pre-drywall picture provided to give insight into the interior of the wall).

What is the best way to install the 5800MICRA into this entry?  Obviously, I don't want to drill up into the transom panels.  Perhaps put the transmitter down into the door and the magnet on the jamb?  Into the side of the door frame, above the windows in the transom?  Not even sure if that would evacuate the dual panel glass panels?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a pic/link of the installation instructions or the unit? It's hard to visualize.